# Finding trigrams for entire corpus with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to write a script that will look through my corpus which contains 93,000 txt files and find the frequency distributions of the trigrams present across all of them (so not separate frequency distributions but one frequency distribution for the entire corpus). I've gotten it to do the frequency distributions for a single file in the corpus but don't have the skills at all to get any further. Here's the code:

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk import FreqDist

corpus_root = '/Users/jolijttamanaha/Python/CRspeeches'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt')

print "Finished importing corpus"

f = speeches.open('Mr. THOMPSON of Pennsylvania.2010-12-07.2014sep17_at_233337.txt')
raw = f.read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
tgs = nltk.trigrams(tokens)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tgs)
for k,v in fdist.items():
    print k,v
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you define your `speeches` corpus with `PlaintextCorpusReader` as you have, you can get trigrams for the entire corpus very simply:

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(nltk.trigrams(speeches.words()))
```

But this has an undesirable glitch: It forms trigrams that span from the end of one file to the next. But such trigrams do not represent tokens that could follow each other in a text-- they are completely accidental. What you really want is to combine the trigram counts from each individual file, which you can get like this:

```
fdist = nltk.FreqDist()  # Empty distribution

for filename in speeches.fileids():
    fdist.update(nltk.trigrams(speeches.words(filename)))
```

Your `fdist` now contains the cumulative statistics, which you can examine in the various available ways. E.g.,

```
fdist.tabulate(10)
```

Comment: Much better solution. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsement, @axiom. If you want more detail than the nltk book provides, I'd go straight to [the source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.html) (which is admittedly a bit of a treasure hunt, since the `CorpusReader` class hierarchy is fairly deep).

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your help. This worked wonderfully for most of my corpora but on one of them I get the following error on the fdist.update line: 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Clearly you're reading a non-ascii file, but not telling it what encoding to read it with. `PlaintextCorpusReader` accepts an `encoding` argument, so find out the encoding of your corpus and use it. Ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For pre-coded corpora API, instead of using `corpus.raw()`, you can try also `corpus.words()`, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.words()
[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', ...]
>>> trigrams = ngrams(brown.words(), 3)
>>> for i in trigrams:
...     print i
```

As @alexis pointed out, the code above should also work for custom corpora loaded with `PlaintextCorpusReader`, see http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.html

Comment: This also works with custom corpora loaded with `PlaintextCorpusReader`.